# Apply promotion code to an incomplete subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm writing an app for a SaaS where customers pay for a monthly subscription and I want to support entering promotion code.

This is the flow:

1. I need to create an incomplete subscription with invoice and payment intent so that I can get a client secret for my client side's `Elements` React component, to be able to show a payment form.
2. After showing the payment form, customer can enter a promotion code to get a discount.
3. I look up the promotion code and add it to the subscription.

All 3 steps happen without any issue but the problem is after doing this, the client still pays the original price (e.g. 100), not discounted. The discount is applied to their "next" invoice, not the existing one.

How can I fix this? I can not create the subscription at the final stage as I need it for `clientSecret` in the client side. And if I do create it early, it cannot be modified after customer wants to apply a promotion code to it.

Comment: Thanks for the clearly worded issue. I have also run into this, and it truely bewilds me how bad the stripe documentation is, and how round-about it seems to be to make the API fit into what I think is an incredibly common use-case.

Comment: Agreed. FWIW I ended up using Stripe checkout sessions and webhooks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I don't suppose you found any good information online how to take that approach utilizing the `react-stripe-js` module.

Comment: I ended up modifying my flow slightly as a shortcut to let the user enter their promotion code, then creating the subscription after that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can [pre-collect](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) the card info using Elements, then create a Subscription [specifying the promotion code](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-promotion_code) you want.